# Smart Playlist in iTunes for songs that contain lyrics

Tags: macos, itunes, smart-playlist

I’m looking for a way to create a Smart Playlist in iTunes that contains only songs without lyrics. 
Or to be more specific, I want to be able to create a Smart Playlist of songs that I haven’t put through [Get Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php) and then run it though the app so that it gets lyrics for the songs that I don’t already have lyrics for.

I’m using iTunes 10.6.3 (25) on a mid 2010 MacBook running Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this with a smart playlist as Apple doesn't expose the lyric field there.

You can create an Applescript that creates a playlist. You'd then have to rerun the script to update the playlist. A track has a playlist field so you'd just check that.

Here's one example of such a script

```
tell application "iTunes"

    if exists playlist "No Lyrics" then
        delete playlist "No Lyrics"
    end if

    make new playlist with properties {name:"No Lyrics"}

   duplicate (every track of playlist 1 whose lyrics is equal to "") to playlist "No Lyrics"

end tell
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I haven’t actually used apple scripts before, but I went ahead and put you suggestion through AppleScript Editor and ran it, and it worked great. I have a question though. Is there a way to make it so that the script only adds songs? like maybe add a property of {media kind: music}? Also, when I ran the script, iTunes was unresponsive and then AppleScript Editor came up with `error “iTunes got an error: AppleEvent timed out.” number −1712` But it seemed to create the playlist and add songs to it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some wacky way to accomplish this, I am fairly sure it is impossible. The smart playlists take certain aspects of a song, and use them to filter through your entire library, looking for matches. They do not check the lyrics.

However, if you were to somehow get your 'Get Lyrical' app to make a minor, consistent change to the song title, or to rate all non lyrical songs a particular rating, then this could be used to filter out only the songs you want.

How to get this to work, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun Get Lyrical on all songs and save a playlist at the end. This is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 0):

[TrackSift 2](http://dougscripts.com/apps/tracksift2app.php) seems to be able to do at least some of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you run Get Lyrical, say Yes to the option to replace existing lyrics.  After it finishes, open the playlist it created of all the songs it did not find lyrics for.